# Vite + Netlify through GitHub repository

Tags: module, vite, styling, production

I'm quite new to ways to deploy a `Vite app`, and trying the easiest way for now for practice and testing.

I have a `github repo`, to which from `VSCode`, I commit my vite app regularly,  excluding in gitignore the node_modules folder.

I have some modules, which styles I have modified in their `node_modules/the-module-itself/dist/module-itself.css` .

That repo is connected into `netlify`, with the default settings, and netlify deploys this app from the repo.

> My problem is that I can not override the CSS styling of the modules I
> have installed in my app.

The modules themselves show in the correct way, but with their own default styling. I suppose it is because the netlify environment when connected with a repo from GitHub, installs every dependency from npm based on the package.json, hence using only the now freshly downloaded module's default CSS.

I tried to override it by

1 - having the correct references for the module (the correct CSS classes) included in the scoped styling of the component, where they render

2 - having it globally declared within the component where they render

3 - having it globally declared within app.vue

Nothing seems to be working, I thought if I declare them at least in the Vue.app (which looks horrible and doesn't feel the right way btw), especially globally,  then that would override the module's styling.

As a plus info so that everything is clear, I'm using modules like vueup(quill editor for vue), vuepic (a calendar based datepicker), etc., which styles obviously need some customizing to match my project.

Could you tell me, how to approach this problem the right way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a probable best solution:

**Importing a seperate css for your module in which you have the original css + your modifications, in the component where the module renders This css file can be saved in basically any folder except the ones you ignore for git, your app will use this imported css**